# Rewrite Path - Show Domain Path Like Subdomain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How can I show domain path like subdomain (with htaccess). I "dont want" to create subdomain and folder ...

I have a path like this for example:

https://example.com/someuser

and want to show this path like a subdomain:

https://someuser.example.com

How can I redirect and show all this pathes as subdomain? I used this but it does not work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/?$ https://$1.example/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't show a different URL or domain. Rewriting generates a new request to the webserver which must be solved.